# Meta refresh HTML tag accessibility error

Tags: html, wordpress, accessibility, wcag, divi

I'm running accessibility tests on my site and am getting this error:
SC 3.2.5 - Tech H76 [WCAG 2.1 (AAA)]Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect
reference link to the error https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H76

but in the code I can't find any Meta refresh.
Reports me with that error these Meta tags:

```
<meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large">
<meta content="Divi Child v.1.0.0" name="generator">
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 6.1.1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
<meta name="tec-api-version" content="v1">
<meta name="tec-api-origin" content="https://test.domain.it">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://test.domain.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-favicon-270x270.png">
```

while instead it does not report these to me as an error:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The site is made with WordPress and with the divi theme, from what I understand I should take off the meta refresh, but I can't find it anywhere, could it be a false positive or is there really an error?
How could I go about solving it if this error really existed?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have a refresh. Is that all the code?  Perhaps a URL to the real page (in addition to posting the code).  Also, WCAG 3.2.5 is a AAA checkpoint. Most scanning tools and all companies that I've worked for only look for A and AA issues. Not AAA. Did you specifically turn on AAA scanning?  What scanning tool are you using.

Comment: @slugolicious use mauve++ and wcga2.1 level AAA.  the problem occurs in all pages so it is surely in the head or in the footer but I don't see any refresh.  otherwise other elements or links could cause this problem?  the meta tags I put up are all there are no others

Comment: Is there a reason you are scanning for AAA? Most accessibility checks are for AA. Can you post a URL so I can try it? It’s possible that mauve has a bug.

Comment: @slugolicious because i'm trying to reach the top level... i added the site in the description above .  now there are also other errors, I think they can be solved, do you also have any advice to solve the others and to correct the contrast of the slider dots?  with level AA it doesn't tell me the meta refresh but I'd prefer to eliminate it altogether if it's really present, thanks

Comment: Regarding scanning for AAA, from the [WCAG 2.1 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#h-note-29), *"It is not recommended that Level AAA conformance be required as a general policy for entire sites because it is not possible to satisfy all Level AAA Success Criteria for some content."*

Comment: Your other questions should be posted as separate questions.

Comment: I just ran https://mauve.isti.cnr.it/singleValidation.jsp on that one page and it didn't show any errors for AA.  When run for AAA, I do see the meta refresh errors. If you go to the "Web Developer" tab, it shows you where in the code it's finding the problems.  The first one is `<meta name="robots">` which is for google scans. I'm not sure why mauve considers that a redirect. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: @slugolicious ok, from what I understand it's quite difficult to reach the AAA level, I'll try to re-compet at least AA ,so do you think it could be a bug ?thanks for the help